# DLL include unordered_map is not compiling with visual studio compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, hashmap, mingw, unordered-map

I am trying to compile a DLL with MinGW and use it from an executable compiled with visual studio compiler.

One of source files from DLL is using hash_map<> and it can be compile with MinGW successfully.

When I change `hash_map<>` to `std::tr1::unordered_map<>` and add `#include <tr1/unordered_map>` to my code it's compiling successfully for visual studio compiler.([How can I force MinGW to use tr1 namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263262/how-can-i-force-mingw-to-use-tr1-namespace))

But When I am trying to compile the code with MinGW as a DLL and use it from an executable compiled with visual studio compiler it's giving error: cannot open include file 'tr/unordered_map'

must My DLL be compatible with cl and MinGW same time?

EDIT:
my commands for compiling are below:

```
g++ -shared -o stemming.dll stemming.cpp alphabet.cpp basic.cpp determinise.cpp fst.cpp hopcroft.cpp operators.cpp utf8.cpp -Wl,--output-def,stemming.def,--out-implib,libstemming.a

lib /machine:i386 /def:stemming.def

cl sfstMinGW.cpp SFST/stemming.lib
```

Comment: All these containers should be part of Dll implementation, and not interface. In this case their headers should be included only to .cpp files, and should not affect Dll client built with another compiler. If you are trying to include templated containers to Dll interface, this is wrong, even for the same compiler.

Comment: Are you actually trying to `#include` **tr** /unordered_map or is that a typo in your question?

Answer (score 0):

VC++ is trying to open a header file and can't find it in the include path. VC uses the `INCLUDE` environment variable to determine the paths to use when searching for header files. Since VC does not use the `tr/` directory it's not going to find it. You need provide include statements for both VC and g++ and choose which one to use like below.

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
# include <unordered_map>
#else
# include <tr/unordered_map>
#endif
```

You need to make sure that you compile the application using the same implementation of `unordered_map` used by the DLL. This means you will need to update the include paths to use GCC's version of TR1 instead of MS's implementation of the standard headers.